# How to remove padding around background image?

Tags: html, css, svg

How to remove "padding" around background image ?

Here is a demo :
https://jsbin.com/dobucizaqi/edit?html,css,output

```css
.foo {
   background-image: url("data:image/svg+xml,%3Csvg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' width='24' height='24' viewBox='0 0 24 24'%3E%3Cpath fill='%23f39c12' d='M3,19V5A2,2 0 0,1 5,3H19A2,2 0 0,1 21,5V19A2,2 0 0,1 19,21H5A2,2 0 0,1 3,19M17,12L12,7V10H8V14H12V17L17,12Z'/%3E%3C/svg%3E");
   background-repeat: no-repeat;
   background-size: 8em 8em;
   height: 8em;
   width: 8em;
}
.bar {
  background-color: red;
  align-items: center;
  display: flex;
}
```

```html
<div class="bar">
  <div class="foo"></div>
  <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
</div>
```

I tried to remove margins and paddings, without success.

I want both left borders to be aligned and remove the "padding" around horizontally and vertically.

Thanks.

V.

Comment: Just wondering, Have you tried `padding: 0px`?

Comment: @Steven Nopes, that's not going to work, it's because of the SVG image file.

Comment: Is it possible that your image by itself has padding?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Simply adjust the viewBox of the SVG:

```css
.foo {
   background-image: url("data:image/svg+xml,%3Csvg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' width='24' height='24' viewBox='3 3 18 18'%3E%3Cpath fill='%23f39c12' d='M3,19V5A2,2 0 0,1 5,3H19A2,2 0 0,1 21,5V19A2,2 0 0,1 19,21H5A2,2 0 0,1 3,19M17,12L12,7V10H8V14H12V17L17,12Z'/%3E%3C/svg%3E");
   background-repeat: no-repeat;
   background-size: 8em 8em;
   height: 8em;
   width: 8em;
}
.bar {
  background-color: red;
  align-items: center;
  display: flex;
}
```

```html
<div class="bar">
  <div class="foo"></div>
  <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks. Both solutions work. I prefer the second which seems easier to use.

Comment: @Vincent there is no magic :) simply adjust them until you get what you want ;) .... first your image is having *padding* like you said so the first idea is to give negative background-position to get rid of it in the left/top then you need to make it bigger [background-size] to get rid of the right/bottom part, that's it ... play with the value and you will understand more ;)

Comment: @Vincent I gave the second solution first. `:)`

Comment: @PraveenKumar no ;) i added the second solution in less than 1min after adding my first one and i didn't even notice your answer [if it was the case i won't add it] ... you can check my edits https://stackoverflow.com/posts/49360591/revisions

Comment: @TemaniAfif I am not blaming you that you copied my answer. Don't worry and the history won't reflect your edits as it was done in less than 5 mins.

Comment: @PraveenKumar i didn't copy your answer, i have both solution in my mind and i posted the first one then edited to add the next one right after my post and i didn't even see you answer ... i will edit my answer so you won't get upset as am not looking for the accepted mark or for more reputation, so the OP will accept yours if we like the CSS one

Comment: @TemaniAfif Again, I am not offended or something man. Don't worry at all! It's totally fine. I am happy! :) :) :) Gave you an upvote myself too. I like your right approach.

Comment: These solutions are not perfect when Svg has round border. See my [update](https://jsbin.com/dobucizaqi/edit?html,css,output).

Comment: @Vincent because not all the SVG are the same :) you need to re-adjust the viewBow of the new SVG and not with the same value of course. I would say each SVG is unique

Comment: @Vincent try this `viewBox='2 2 20 20'` with the second svg and it will work :)

Answer (score 2):

Either you can adjust the viewbox of SVG, or you can do it using CSS:

```
.foo {
  background-image: url("data:image/svg+xml,%3Csvg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' width='24' height='24' viewBox='0 0 24 24'%3E%3Cpath fill='%23f39c12' d='M3,19V5A2,2 0 0,1 5,3H19A2,2 0 0,1 21,5V19A2,2 0 0,1 19,21H5A2,2 0 0,1 3,19M17,12L12,7V10H8V14H12V17L17,12Z'/%3E%3C/svg%3E");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: 130%;
  background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.25);
  background-position: -10px -10px;
  height: 4em;
  width: 4em;
}
```

**Snippet**

```css
.foo {
  background-image: url("data:image/svg+xml,%3Csvg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' width='24' height='24' viewBox='0 0 24 24'%3E%3Cpath fill='%23f39c12' d='M3,19V5A2,2 0 0,1 5,3H19A2,2 0 0,1 21,5V19A2,2 0 0,1 19,21H5A2,2 0 0,1 3,19M17,12L12,7V10H8V14H12V17L17,12Z'/%3E%3C/svg%3E");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: 130%;
  background-position: -10px -10px;
  height: 4em;
  width: 4em;
}
.bar {
  background-color: red;
  align-items: center;
  display: flex;
}
```

```html
<div class="bar">
  <div class="foo"></div>
  <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
</div>
```

**Preview**

[image: preview]